# Open problems in Lie theory

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, big-list, open-problem

I been studying Lie theory for some time. Beside classification related problems what are some examples of open problems in the lie world? Especifically in the topological/differentiable structure of these?

Are there any conjectures arising from mathematical physics? For example in Poisson geometry?

Comment: This is extremely broad. It definitely meets the criteria for the close reason. When you say "the Lie world," you're describing an enormous portion of modern mathematics, so there are probably thousands of open problems in the area that people are actively working on. You'll need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Especifically  sounds like a nice [portmanteau word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau).